MAUI SecureStorage 'Error adding record: MissingEntitlement'
I'm working on window using MAUI and I am building for android and ios platfoms.
Here is the code work well on Android but get error 'Error adding record: MissingEntitlement' on ios
await SecureStorage.SetAsync("access_token", userAccount.token);

I am using a ios simulator connect from a mac.
In Platforms/iOS/Info.plist, I added these code
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.[my app id here]</string>
</array>

Any idea to solve it?

To use the SecureStorage APIs on iOS you will need to enable the right entitlements in the Apple provisioning profile for your app.
This is described in the Microsoft Docs as well.

When developing on the iOS simulator, enable the Keychain entitlement and add a keychain access group for the application's bundle identifier.
Create or open the Entitlements.plist in the project and find the Keychain entitlement and enable it. This will automatically add the application's identifier as a group. For more information about editing the Entitlements.plist file, see Entitlements.
In the project properties, under iOS Bundle Signing set the Custom Entitlements to Entitlements.plist.

An additional tip is listed as well:

When deploying to an iOS device, this entitlement isn't required and should be removed.


Can you add plist entries that need to be added ? I'm from VS Code on Mac and not editor seems available like Visual Studio on Windows.
